# NSSavePanel Changing File Name Extensions With AccessoryView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I have **NSSavePanel** with **accessoryView** to let the user select a graphic format so that they can save an image (NSImage) as a file.  So far, I have the following.  (I'm skipping some lines to make it short.)

```
- (void)exportFile {    
    NSString *filename;
    if (formatIndex1 == 0) { // Default selection by user in Preferences
        filename = @"Untitled.bmp";
    }
    else if (formatIndex1 == 1) {
        filename = @"Untitled.gif";
    }
    ...

    [panel setAllowedFileTypes:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"bmp",@"gif",@"jpg",@"jp2",@"png",nil]];
    [panel setAllowsOtherFileTypes:NO];
    [panel setExtensionHidden:NO];
    [panel setCanCreateDirectories:YES];
    [panel setNameFieldStringValue:filename];
    [panel setAccessoryView:accessoryView1];
    [formatMenu1 setAction:@selector(dropMenuChange:)]; // formatMenu1 is NSPopUpButton
    [formatMenu1 setTarget:self];

    [panel beginSheetModalForWindow:window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
        if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
            // getting panel url
        }
    }];
}

-(void)dropMenuChange:(NSPopUpButton *)sender { 
    NSSavePanel *savePanel = (NSSavePanel *)[sender window];
    [savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:@"..."];
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that I'm doing it right.  What I want to achieve is that I want to append the right extension to the current file name whenever the user selects a file format on accessoryView's NSPopUpButton.  Is there a magical way of doing that?  Or do I have to set the current file name with the right extension to **setNameFieldStringValue** programmatically for myself?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set current file name with the right extension using  `setNameFieldStringValue`

```
-(void)dropMenuChange:(NSPopUpButton *)sender { 
    NSSavePanel *savePanel = (NSSavePanel *)[sender window];
    NSString *nameFieldString = [savePanel nameFieldStringValue];
    NSString *nameFieldStringWithExt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[savePanel nameFieldStringValue], popupvalue];
    [savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:nameFieldStringWithExt];
}
```

Answer (score 17):

*What I want to achieve is that I want to append the right extension to the current file name whenever the user selects a file format on accessoryView's NSPopUpButton. Is there a magical way of doing that?*

Yes, there is. You need not do it yourself with `setNameFieldStringValue:` , let the savePanel do it. Let us assume `fileName` is a full path like `/Users/hg/Pictures/2013/08/Airplanes/pic123.png` and it exists an accessoryView for the savePanel with a `matrix of radio buttons`. Each button has a title like @"jpg" or @"png" or... The action of the matrix is `-selectFileType:`

```
- (IBAction) selectFileType:(id)sender
{
    [savePanel setAllowedFileTypes:@[ [[sender selectedCell] title] ] ];
    // this will set the right extension
}
```

For using the savePanel I tried the following code:

```
- (void) saveImage:(NSImage *) theImg
{
  savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
  NSString *imageName = [fileName lastPathComponent];
  NSString *suffix = [imageName pathExtension];
  NSString *baseName = [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension];

  // prepare the savePanel
  [savePanel setAccessoryView:accessoryView];
  [savePanel setAllowedFileTypes:@[ suffix ] ];
  [savePanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName]];  // convert to URL
  [savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:baseName ];  // without extension !
  // savePanel does append the suffix

  // and now start the savePanel and choose the wanted fileType
  int rtn = [savePanel runModal];   // preferred method since 10.6
  if( rtn==NSFileHandlingPanelCancelButton) return;    // do nothing

  // finally create and save the file
  if( [[[savePanel allowedFileTypes] objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"jpg" ){
      // save as jpg-file
  }
  // check for other fileTypes
  . . . 
}
```

Comment: This is really the correct answer as `setNameFieldStringValue:` does not update the filename and extension on an already open NSSavePanel

Comment: Using setAllowedFileTypes surprisingly works. The function name seems to mean what file extensions are valid, however I found that setting a list of valid file types in an array did not work. Calling setAllowedFileTypes with an array of a single element as suggested above does work. Mark this one as another confusing AppKit function that needs to be redone/renamed.

Comment: Agreed. This is the correct answer. I'd also like to add the following for clarification... Setting `allowedFileTypes` to an array with a single variable is the trick. For example, if you want the file type to change to png you would... `savePanel.allowedFileTypes = ["png"]`... In my app, when a user selects a filetype option from an NSPopupButton in my accessoryView, it triggers a method that invokes something similar to line of code above.